# is sprintf thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

is `sprintf` thread safe ?

```
//Global log buffer 
char logBuffer[20];

logStatus (char * status, int length)
{
  snprintf(logBuffer, 19, status);
  printf ("%s\n", logBuffer);
}
```

The thread safety of this function totally depends upon the thread safety of `snprintf`/`sprintf` .

**Updates :**
thanks for ur answers . 
i dont mind, if the actual contents gts messed up. but want to confirm that the sprintf would not cause a memory corruption / buffer overflow going beyond 20 bytes in this case,  when multiple threads are trying to write to `logBuffer` ?

Comment: If your actual need is to limit the strings printed to no more than 19 characters, use `printf("%.19s\n", status);`.

Comment: the actual application is much elaborate to explain here. This function is  extremely stripped down version of the code ! Hope you get the point :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no problem using `snprintf()` in multiple threads. But here you are writing to a shared string buffer, which I assume is shared across threads.

So *your use* of this function would *not* be thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has an incorrect premise. Even if `sprintf` itself can be safely called from multiple threads at the same time (as I sure hope it can), your code is not protecting your global variable. The standard library can't possibly help you there.

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems with your code.

1. Your usage of `snprintf` is very suspicious. Don't use it just to
   copy a string. Generally don't pass dynamically allocated strings
   with whatever content as format to any of the `printf` functions.
   They interpret the contents and if there is anything in them that
   resembles a %-format, you are doomed.
2. Don't use `static` buffers as you do. This is certainly neither
   thread safe not re-entrant.
3. Either use `printf` with an appropriate format directly, or replace
   the call by `puts`.

Then, Linux adheres to the POSIX standard, which requires that the standard IO functions are thread safe.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your update about not worrying if the `logBuffer` content get garbled:

I'm not sure why you want to avoid making your function completely thread safe by using a locally allocated buffer or some synchronization mechanism, but if you want to know what POSIX has to say about it, here you go (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

> Applications shall ensure that access to any memory location by more than one thread of control (threads or processes) is restricted such that no thread of control can read or modify a memory location while another thread of control may be modifying it. Such access is restricted using functions that synchronize thread execution and also synchronize memory with respect to other threads. [followed by a list of functions which provide synchronization]

So, POSIX says that your program needs to make sure mutilple threads won't be modifying `logBuffer` concurrently (or modifying `logBuffer` in one thread while reading it in another). If you don't hold to that, there's no promise made that the worst that will happen is garbled data in `logBuffer`.  There's simply no promise made at all about what the results will be.  I don't know if Linux might document a more specific behavior, but I doubt it does.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but the question is about the sprintf behavior under multiple threads with same buffer. and NOT about how to write a multi threaded application to use a buffer !

Comment: @Jay D: So you have multiple threads reading/modifying the same buffer concurrently without synchronization - they just happen to be doing it through `sprintf()`/`snprintf()`.  The behavior is undefined in POSIX; I'm not sure what else you're looking for.  I don't think you'll get anyone to say that the worst you'll ever see is a garbled `logBuffer`, even if that's by far the most likely problem you'll ever see.

Comment: @Michael Burr My program **crashes** *now and then* when using such code snippet which looks like the one in this post.

Answer (score 3):

"There is no problem using `snprintf()` in multiple threads."

Not true.

Not true, at least in case of POSIX functions.

All of the standard `vararg` functions are not mt-safe - this includes all the `printf()` family (1), but also every other `variadic` function as well (2)

1. `sprintf()` for example is: "MT-Safe locale|AS-Unsafe heap|AC-Unsafe mem" - what means, that it can fail if locale is set asynchronously or if asynchronous cancellation of threads is used. In other words, special attention must be paid when using such functions in MT environment.
2. `va_arg` is not mt-safe: |MT-Safe race:ap|AS-Safe|AC-Unsafe corrupt| - what means, that inter-locking is needed.

Additionally, what should be obvious, even totally mt-safe function can be used in unsafe way - what happens for example if two or more threads are operating the same data/memory areas.

Comment: Do you have a refernce which says that they are not thread safe? When I Google, it seems that they are

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I have the same question as Mawg says reinstate Monica's.

Comment: @John  I think you meant to address vtomazzi, I just edited his answer and didn't post it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not thread safe, since the buffer where you sprintf is shared between all threads.

Answer (score 0):

"Do you have a refernce which says that they are not thread safe? When I Google, it seems that they are"

My previous answer to this question has been removed/deleted (why?), so I'll try again, using different approach:

1. AC (async. cancellation of threads): this is obviously a case when almost all of the "apparently MT-safe" code can fail, simply because the thread is interrupted at a random point of time, so none of synchronization methods are guaranted to work correctly (i.e. any form of mutex can't be really guranteed to work correctly)
2. Threads can use the same malloc() arena, what means, that if one of the threads will fail (i.e. it'll damage the malloc arena) then all the consecutive calls to malloc() will/can cause critical errors - this of course depends on system configuration - but it also means, that nobody should assume that malformed memory (de)allocations are safe.

Since all of the systems are providing the option to use different local settings, it is obvious, that async. change to the "locale" settings can cause errors...

Regards.

Comment: Why do you not just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30631615/edit) your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30631615/5292302) or respond to the =[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386352/is-sprintf-thread-safe/45123379#comment67306648_30631615) under that answer, people will not understand that you are responding to a comment on your answer this way. It seems that you are responding to the initial question, btw this is probably why your previous answer (response) to the comment was deleted.