# Segmentation fault in snprintf when using OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I've read somewhere that snprintf is thread safe; however, when I run my code it produces a segmentation fault.

The main function:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    #pragma omp for private(j)
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            foo(gene_seq); //gene_seq is a large char array
        }
    }
}
```

And the line of code that is faulty:

```
double foo(char *gene_seq){
    char *seq;

    /* some stuff above */
    region_length = end_pos-init_pos+1; // include \0 terminator
    seq = (char *)safe_malloc(sizeof(char) * region_length);
    snprintf(seq, region_length, "%s", gene_seq + init_pos); //SIGSEGV!!!
    /*more stuff*/
}
```

EDIT Updated the program around the snprintf line to this:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
    snprintf(seq, region_length, "%s", gene_seq + init_pos);
}
```

And it still fails to execute. gdb gives me the following values to the variables:

```
(gdb) p strlen(gene_seq)
$1 = 1405
(gdb) p init_pos
$2 = 683
(gdb) p region_length
$4 = 221
```

When I execute the program single-threaded it runs fine, and gdb isn't very helpful. My version of glibc is 2.15. Will provide more info if needed.

Comment: Any chance you are reading off the end of gene_seq?

Comment: I don't think that `snprintf` is generally thread-safe. Perhaps you read that one particular implementation was? It would help if you remembered where you saw that, of course.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386352/is-sprintf-thread-safe

Comment: @dohashi no, gene_seq is a big sequence, and init_pos is a small number. As stated before, when I execute the program single-threaded it runs fine.

Comment: @PascalCuoq also, this link confirms that snprintf is thread safe: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fs%2Fsnprintf.html

Comment: @ManuelReis I think that it confirms that at least one snprintf is thread-safe. Are you using QNX?

Comment: Are your calculations for `end_pos` and `init_pos` thread safe (and atomic)?

Comment: @PascalCuoq No, I'm using Ubuntu. Perhaps it isn't really thread-safe, and the buffer is shared between all threads. The manpage doesn't shed a light on the matter.

Comment: @pmg I believe so, as all of these variables are declared and used inside the parallel for directive (they are not global, and as they are declared inside that for they don't need to be private, but I could be wrong).

Comment: Maybe you read `gene_seq` to calculate those variables and write to it for other reasons making those variables have *strange* values.

Comment: @alk This comment seems like an answer

Comment: @pmg The `gene_seq` variable is only written once, before spawing new threads. From then on it is only read.

Comment: Did you compile providing the option `-pthread`.

Comment: What does Valgrind tell you?

Comment: @alk no, I compiled the program using -fopenmp. I will try to run it with a critical block in that section, to see if it is indeed thread safe or not, before running it with valgrind.

Comment: What happens if you remove the cast from malloc and compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`?

Comment: @alk no relevant warnings appear. Compiles ok. SIGSEGV keeps happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60912/discussion-between-manuel-reis-and-alk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be you missed to protoytype `safe_malloc()` **and** are on 64bits?

If "Yes" the compiler assumes `safe_alloc()` to return 32 bits and therefore returns an invalid pointer if the the pointer's value is larger then 2^32.

Switch on all warnings `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and listen to what the compiler tells you.

Comment: The problem was indeed the missing prototype, that led to some strange behaviour around that `safe_malloc` call. Switching the warnings on helped me find the problem!

Comment: I also take the time to say that snprintf seems to be thread safe, in the scope of the question made.

Comment: `man 7 pthreads` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) referrs to which functions shall be thread-safe and which not under which assumptions. @ManuelReis